# Create a dynamic view based on partitioned tables

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

We have a large database with monthly partitioned tables.  I need to aggregate a selection of these tables every month but I don't want to update the union all every month to add the new monthly table.

```
CREATE VIEW dynamic_view AS
SELECT timestamp, 
       traffic
FROM traffic_table_m_2017_01
UNION ALL 
SELECT timestamp, 
       traffic
FROM traffic_table_m_2017_02
```

Is this where I would use a stored procedure?  I am not really familiar with them.

I think it would also work as:

```
SELECT timestamp, 
       traffic
FROM REPLACE(REPLACE('traffic_table_m_yyyy_mm', 
                     yyyy, FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy', 'en-us')),
                     mm, FORMAT(GETDATE(),'mm', 'en-us'));
```

This might work for the current month but I would need to save the data from the past months which would also be an issue.

Comment: Your first port of call should be to use aws redshift features like distribution and sort key rather than table partitioning, have you tried this? . Redshift does not support/handle partitioning and it does not adapt well to hacking a partition structure with a view. You may find that you do not get the performance you expect .

Comment: Thanks @JonScott, I am not familiar with distribution and sort key.  I will look into them.  This is a job that would only run on a weekly or monthly basis so performance is not critical.  Moving the same data to a new db would require an extensive etl process that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: you are using redshift right? moving the data once per month within redshift will be very fast.

Comment: Yes, it is Redshift.  for some reason we only have the summary tables that are required for this particular usecase.  Typically, I would use the aggregate table and that would solve the issue.

Comment: If you know the range (no of months) then you could generate a dynamic SQL and execute it

Comment: @SriniV, so lets assume that we can do this for the next 20 years.  What would that look like?

Answer (score 1):

you should append each table as it arrives to 1 larger table then run your queries against that. there are many ways to do this but probable the fastest and most elegant is to use.
ALTER TABLE APPEND
Instructions here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE_APPEND.html